# ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED when Chrome console is open

Tags: google-chrome, console

This problem has appeared a few days ago with this message into the console:

```
GET http://any_url net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```

Pages work fine as soon the console is closed

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I had the same problem. Open the console, select the "Network" and choose "not throttling" instead "offline".

Comment: OMG, I was debuging OIDC flow with slow3g/offline on localhost a week ago, and I didn't develop in this computer, and forgot this whole settings. Today it was 3 hours of debug the set it back online. :D Thanks for this comment!

Comment: omg i forgot to revert this when playing with the feature and was driving me crazy thank you