# React PWA fails to reload in Chrome Dev Tools

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, service-worker, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I try to create PWA via create-react-app.

React: 16.8.4

React-Scripts: 2.1.8

Chrome: 72.0.3626.121

The minimum setup to reproduce this is:

Edit `src/index.js`and change `serviceWorker.unRegister()` to `serviceWorker.register()`.

Create a production build and serve the app

`npm run build && serve -s build`

Browse to http://localhost:5000 and see my app.

When I enter offline mode (stop the server or select offline in the Network tab) and hit reload, the browser loads the app, obviously via the service worker.

When I open Chrome dev tools and hit reload while being offline, the browser shows me ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED, the service worker is not doing anything in debug mode.

In Firefox, the app works offline both normal and in the Firefox debugger.

What can I do to debug a service worker in Chrome?

Comment: If you have gone into [this workaround posted in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33063539/err-internet-disconnected-when-chrome-console-is-open), that when you open a console under the "Network" instead of choosing "offline" try the "not throttling".

Comment: Thanks, my version of Chrome seems to have no "not throttling" option. Maybe the referred post describes an older version of Chrome (Oct 17 '15 ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that I had checked *Bypass for Network* in the *Application* tab. In that case any request goes directly to the network which renders the service worker useless.